# Assign to underscore

Tags: swift

In the tests folder of the swift language source, I found this mysterious line:

```
func attrs() {
  _ = {(z: inout Int) -> Int in z }
}
```

Another line says:

```
let _: (x: Int, y: Int) -> Int = { (x, y) in x + y }
```

How does this code behave?

Reference: [https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/expr/closure/basic.swift [34, 40]](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/expr/closure/basic.swift)

Comment: have you read the swift guide? search for underscore on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html

Comment: Only found parameter specific answers

Comment: An underscore (_) parameter is explicitly ignored and can’t be accessed within the body of the function.